# Returning a value if there is an specific match

Tags: excel-formula

I'm working on an smal project on which I have to analyze orders if the were fully completed or not. In the column "status" I have the raw data pulled from my reporting tool with the tags "completed" or "INCOMPLETED". In the column Review I want to enter a formula that will return INCOMPLETED because one or more lines within the same order# was not completed. Any suggestions wil do. THX.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is located at `B2:E11` enter this formula in `E3` and copy till `E11`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($C$3:$C$11,$C3,$D$3:$D$11,"INCOMPLETED")>0,"INCOMPLETED","COMPLETED")
```

Comment: Thank you @EEM! Worked perfectly. I'm now having another challenge :S

Comment: You are welcome, please accept the answer and help us to keep the site updated...